# How to work with a copy of realm database

Tags: swift, database, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm working on XCODE, I did a copy of a realm database from default.realm to
user_xxx.realm. I need to manage several users in the same device. So I have added a suffixe. The new database seems empty, it's work on the simulator but not on a real device, any idea?

```
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let realmNew = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("database_" + String(id) + ".realm")
    let realmDefault = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")

                do {
                    //try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: realmDefault, to: realmNew)
                    try fileManager.copyItem(atPath: realmDefault.path, toPath: realmNew.path)
                    result = "STEP 3"
                    migration = true  
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    result = "STEP 4"
                    print("Ooops! Something went wrong: \(error)")
                }

    config.fileURL = realmNew
    Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config
```

Comment: Something very weird, I know why it's empty, I have seen 2 databases default.realm and a second ont drafts.realm. the second database stored all the data. Need Realm team for more information.